# Maintain Gridview Checkbox state after moving Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

this is my remember values code for checkbox

```
private void RememberOldGridValues()
    {
        ArrayList oUserCheckedList = new ArrayList();           
        int index = -1;
        int Value=0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewResults.Rows)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked)
            {
                index = row.RowIndex;
                Value=(int)gridViewResults.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
                if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
                    oUserCheckedList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
                if (oUserCheckedList.Count == 1)
                {
                    oUserCheckedList.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                if (!oUserCheckedList.Contains(index))
                    oUserCheckedList.Add(index);
                    oUserCheckedList.Add(Value);
            }
            if (index >= 0)
                break;
        }
        if (oUserCheckedList != null && oUserCheckedList.Count > 0)
            Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = oUserCheckedList;
    }
```

and this is repopulates I'm not able to get datatime in grid view.

```
private void RePopulateGridValues()
    {
        int value;
        ArrayList oUserCheckedList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
        if (oUserCheckedList != null && oUserCheckedList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewResults.Rows)
            {
                string str = oUserCheckedList[0].ToString();
                value=Convert.ToInt32(oUserCheckedList[1].ToString());
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(str);
                if (row.RowIndex == i)
                {
                    if (value == Convert.ToInt32(row.DataItemIndex.ToString()))
                    {
                        CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                        myCheckBox.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice - [Grid View checkbox view state](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5664497/102112)?

Comment: I have give an idea to, as you are questioning again and again. no one will provide you complete code. try my answer.. Good Luck :)

Comment: you can delete my question it was mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are repopulating your Gridview Checkboxes in the wrong way. You have to use a RowDatabound Event.

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
         if (ArrayCollection.Find(dr["KeyColumnName"].ToString()))
//Dont try to store the index of your Grid and checkbox value, as if the page Index    change your Grid Index will will change. try to store KeyColumnName Value and then compare here and upon bases of set Checkbox = Chcekced
            {
                 CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                 myCheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what i need to store in array collection at time of RememberOldGridValues()

Comment: yes, you need to store, but when you back on the page, you have to use above technique to tick checkboxes.

Comment: ok wht about pagination in gridview if i want to check only one check box at a time consder i have 16 records and 2 pages this is something wht iam writing

Comment: that's why I am asking you to put Primary Key column in your arraylist instead row index. No matter on what page you are, as the key Column have unique in every row. Its best way to maintain gridview checkboxes state.